# How to put a condition in jQuery Elevate Zoom Object Options?

Tags: jquery, elevatezoom

I am using this object for my elevate zoom:

```
$("#zoom_09").elevateZoom({
   zoomType: "inner",
});
```

I want to change it for mobile screens like this:

```
$("#zoom_09").elevateZoom({  
  zoomType: if($(window).width < 767){ "inner" }else { "window" }
});
```

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug, with no current solution: https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/issues/94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this will definitely work.

```
  if($(window).width() < 767){ 
  $("#zoom_09").elevateZoom({
    zoomType : "inner" 

  }); 
  }
  else{
   $("#zoom_09").elevateZoom({
    zoomType : "window" 

});
```

Comment: Thanks Waseem, Its working, will change it for window.resize too myself...